# How did file identify this particular file?

Tags: file-command

I'm running `file` against a wallet.dat file (A file that Bitcoin keeps its private keys in) and even though there doesn't seem to be any identifiable header or string, `file` can still tell that it's a Berkley DB file, even if I cut it down to 16 bytes.

I know that file was applying some sort of rule or searching for some sequence to identify it. I want to know what the rule it's applying here is, so that I can duplicate it in my own program.

Comment: file is not infallible, it just makes guesses based on the content of the file, the "tuesday printing bug' is one example of where it was guessing wrong

Comment: @Jasen `file` isn't wrong in this circumstance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Grab the source of the file command. Most if not all open sources unices use [this one](http://www.darwinsys.com/file/). The `file` command comes with the `magic` database, named after the [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) that it describes. (This database is also installed on your live system, but in a compiled form.) Look for the file that contains the description text that you see:

```
grep 'Berkeley DB' magic/Magdir/*
```

The [`magic` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/magic.4.html) describes the format of the file. The trigger lines for “Berkeley DB” are

```
0       long    0x00061561      Berkeley DB
0       belong  0x00061561      Berkeley DB
12      long    0x00061561      Berkeley DB
12      belong  0x00061561      Berkeley DB
12      lelong  0x00061561      Berkeley DB
12      long    0x00053162      Berkeley DB
12      belong  0x00053162      Berkeley DB
12      lelong  0x00053162      Berkeley DB
12      long    0x00042253      Berkeley DB
12      belong  0x00042253      Berkeley DB
12      lelong  0x00042253      Berkeley DB
12      long    0x00040988      Berkeley DB
12      belong  0x00040988      Berkeley DB 
12      lelong  0x00040988      Berkeley DB
```

The first column specifies the offset at which a certain byte sequence is to be found. The third column contains the byte sequence. The second column describes the type of byte sequence: `long` means 4 bytes in the platform's [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness); `lelong` and `belong` mean 4 bytes in little-endian and big-endian order respectively.

Rather than replicate the rules, you may want to call the `file` utility; it's [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/file.html), but the formats that it recognizes and the descriptions that it outputs aren't. Alternatively, you can link to `libmagic` and call the `magic_file` or `magic_buffer` function.

Answer (score 10):

You could:

1. Run `file` from within your program
2. Use a library that provides `file`'s functionality to your programming language.  e.g. `libmagic` for C, `File::Libmagic` or `File::MMagic` for `perl`, `python-magic` for python, etc.

BTW, the definitions that `file` uses to identify files are are found in `/etc/magic`.  See `man 5 magic` for file format details.

Comment: On Linux `/etc/magic` tends to be for your own local magic knowledge.  Distros tend to pop their generic magic in `/usr/share/misc/magic`.

Comment: I ended up just reading the source: https://github.com/file/file/blob/c961dc8a10d0785d96f0c4fc88a96fc1f9fc0878/magic/Magdir/database#L27